# Function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ totally differentiable at zero

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

**Problem:** Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ be a function that satisfies $\Vert f(x) \Vert \leq \Vert x \Vert^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that $f$ is totally differentiable at $0$ and determine $(df)(0)$.

**Attempt:** We need to prove that there exists a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ such that $$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n : 0 < \Vert x \Vert < \delta \Rightarrow \frac{ \Vert f(x) - f(0) - A(x) \Vert }{\Vert x \Vert} < \epsilon. $$

I was trying to manipulate the inequality: $$ \frac{ \Vert f(x) - f(0) - A(x) \Vert }{\Vert x \Vert} \leq \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert } \bigg( \Vert f(x) - f(0) \Vert + \Vert A(x) \Vert \bigg) \\ \leq \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert } \bigg( \Vert f(x) \Vert + \Vert f(0) \Vert + \Vert A \Vert \Vert x  \Vert \bigg) \leq \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert } \bigg( \Vert x \Vert^2 + \Vert f(0) \Vert + \Vert A \Vert \Vert x  \Vert \bigg) = \\  \Vert x \Vert + \frac{ \Vert f(0) \Vert}{\Vert x \Vert} + \Vert A \Vert . $$ I can get $\Vert x \Vert$ small, but I don't know what to do with the norm of the matrix. Also, there is no information given on what $f(0)$ is.

How to solve this problem? Help appreciated.

Comment: Use your inequality to determine $f(0)$. Now the best candidate for matrix $A$ would be matrix with $0$ everywhere.

Comment: How do you know that the matrix $A$ contains only zeros? Can I just declare that and then go on with the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First see for yourself the case $n=k=1$. It will help you see that this is easy.

You have $\|f (0)\|\leq\|0\|=0$, so $f (0)=0$ (there are three different meanings of "$0$" ther, make sure you are comfortable with that). As in the dimension 1 case, take $A=0$. Then  $$\frac {\|f (x)-f (0)-0\|}{\|x\|}=\frac {\|f (x)\|}{\|x\|}\leq\frac {\|x\|^2}{\|x\|}=\|x\|\to0. $$